# Set form input value to "" doesn't clear spaces

Tags: javascript, forms, key-events

I am trying to implement a command line emulator in JavaScript. I want the `Spacebar` key to act as `Enter` (submit, then clear the command line).

In this post, let's represent a `space` as an underscore, so `_` means `[space]`:

If I enter `banana_` and then, after catching the keypress, I call `input.value= ""`, it clears `banana`, but not the remaining `space`.

I tested both `onkeydown` and `onkeypress`, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Actually, `onkeyup` does the trick, see my answer below!

This is my code. Could someone please help me remove the extra space...

```
<html><head>

<script type="text/javascript">  

    document.onkeypress = keyCheck;  

    function keyCheck( e ) {  
        var keyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : ( e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode );  
        switch(keyID) {  
            case 32: //spacebar  
                alert( "space pressed, clearing..." );  
                document.getElementById( "cli" ).value="";  
                break;  
            default:  
                //do something else  
                break;  
            } 
        }  
</script>  
</head>  

<body>
  <form name="frm" id="frm" onSubmit="go( this )">
  <input name="cli" id="cli" type="text" name="cmd" size="122">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onkeyup` instead.

```
document.onkeyup = keyCheck;
```

This way the event occurs *after* the character has been added to the value of the element.

**Try it out:** http://jsbin.com/esacu3

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks. I'm sorry, I thought I already tested this, turns out I didn't or something. Is there a reason why "onkeypress" doesn't clear the space, but "onkeyup" does? (I thought 'onkeypress' waited both for "onkeyup" and "onkeydown" to finish).

Comment: @Hans - Because the `onkeypress` event fires *before* the character gets added to the input, so the sequence goes *handler fires > value is cleared > character is added*. With `onkeyup`, the handler fires *after* the character is added to the value, so *character is added > handler fires > value is cleared*. What makes `onkeypress` different from `onkeydown` is that it continuously fires if you hold down a key.